Does HomeKit support hardware accessories that can trigger scenes and devices?
I want to activate HomeKit scenes from a hardware accessory switch like a wallbox/lightswitch form factor or other wired or wireless device. I haven't been able to find anything that seems to accomplish this -- only items like the Eve Light Switch, which basically does the opposite -- it is a switch and relay that can be controlled by HomeKit and is designed to have its own connected load to be controlled. I want to have a hardware switch that can be configured to invoke an arbitrary scene or accessory in my home.
Based on the lack of accessories I've found, and the fact that I have found a few solutions that look like workarounds (using Home Assistant, or creating "magic number" dimmer setpoints for a special device that will act as a trigger criteria for HomeKit), I have a suspicion that the HomeKit platform specification simply does not accommodate this. I think it's plausible that Apple wants the user to invoke scenes using the Home app from a device or a Siri command, but in my particular use case I am trying to bridge the gap from these interfaces to the end user who would prefer to interact with a hardware device, for example a Philips Hue Tap Switch or a Lutron Pico Remote.
Does HomeKit offer any support for an accessory device that strictly sends control signals to other Scenes and devices in the Home?

Please post this on Internet of Things

@RohitGupta… is that not where we are?
